# Implementing socket.io in loopBack 4

Tags: typescript, socket.io, client-server, loopback, loopback4

I have tried socket.io in node JS and it works fine. When I tried to integrate socket.io in loopback 4 it is not working as expected. I surfed the problem in google as well as in the lb4 documentation but I did not found any solutions.

I tried with the LoopBack 4 documentation that they have provided.

Answer (score 0):

socketio is available in loopback extensions and can be readily used in a loopback application.
https://github.com/loopbackio/loopback-next/tree/master/extensions/socketio

We have a chat notification example using socketio connection, you can have a look at it here

https://github.com/sourcefuse/loopback4-microservice-catalog/tree/master/sandbox/chat-notification-socketio-example

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).